# VB.net Datatable dynamic columns Query fields with LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic, datatable

For a project i'm trying to make a dynamic query to a datatable field.
Let me explain what i'm doing. 
Step 1. Read database file with OLEDB and create snapshot to datatable.
Step 2. Create dynamically checkboxes that represents the field names from the datatable.
Step 3. User can create query by selecting the checkboxes. Thus filtering the result.

The problem that i'm having is that i don't know upfront how many and what name's the Fields/Column are getting in the datatable. It is no problem making the query if i fill in the Field names hardcoded:

```
 MyDataview = (From p In MyDataTable _
                      Where p.Field(Of Boolean)("customer") = True And _
                            p.Field(Of Boolean)("customer_ID") = True
                            Select p).AsDataView
```

However this would be a problem in the future as the database therefore datatable could change and expand or shrink.

So in SQL syntax this wouldn't be any problem. Simple append the field name that correspondent with the checkbox to a Where clause and where good to go.

This is exactly what i'm trying to achieve. I have searched for many hours and tried allot with system.linq.dynamic but i can't get it to work. example:

```
        Dim valueQuery = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable.Where("customer").[Select]("customer")

        causes exception: 
        No property or field 'customer' exists in type 'DataRow'
```

Or

```
Dim valueQuery = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable.Where("Field=customer").[Select]("customer")
```

causes exception:

> No property or field 'customer' exists in type 'DataRow'

Comment: I'm not quite clear, so you're saying the field called "customer" may or may not exist within your result set?  if that's the case, then it should just be a question of checking if the field exists before attempting to query against it...

Comment: Happy to explain further: The datatable consists of columns(fields) and rows. Sometimes the datatable can have 4 columns (fields) or more or less. (dynamic) The user makes a query of the presented columns. So let's say i have four columns: Customer - CustomerID - Company - Email. For these columns there are 4 checkboxes dynamicly created. The user now select the checkboxes CustomerID - Email. Thus resulting in the following query: p.Field(Of Boolean)("customerID") AND p.Field(Of Boolean)("email"). so far no problem because i KNOW the fields names. But what if i don't know? or there are more?

Comment: @Gforse, All your columns are `Boolean`?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I find out that i was looking for the wrong answer. @octavioccl, Your question is good, yes almost all the columns are booleans. So i have to validate that :     Where p.Field(Of Boolean)("customer") = Checkbox.checked. That brings me on the tricky part. this validation could be one field to one checkbox (dynamically created) or it could be 10 fields with and's and or's